# How can I convert a string containing data in a specific format into an array of associative arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a string with the following format:

```php
$data = "sku=32300905,color=Dark Brown|sku=32300899,color=Blue|sku=32300900,color=Grey|sku=32300914,color=light Brown";
```

And I want to transform this string into an array of associative arrays as shown below:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sku] => 32300905
            [color] => Dark Brown
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sku] => 32300899
            [color] => Blue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sku] => 32300900
            [color] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sku] => 32300914
            [color] => light Brown
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sku] => 12345678
            [color] => 
        )

)
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this conversion in PHP?

Comment: So the `sku` in your resulting arrays should _always_ have the value `color`, and the actual sku _value_ is supposed to become a property name, under which then the actual color _value_ will get stored - really? What would you need _that_ structure for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way to get you response

```
$data = "sku=32300905,color=Dark Brown|sku=32300899,color=Blue|sku=32300900,color=Grey|sku=32300914,color=light Brown";

$convertToArray = explode('|', $data);
$result = array_map(function ($pair) {

    list($key, $value) = explode(',', $pair);
    return array_combine(explode('=', $key), explode('=', $value));

}, $convertToArray);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Or you can also do like this

```
$convertToArray = explode('|', $data);
        
        $result = array_map(function ($item) {
            $sku = null;
            $color = null;
        
            $newArray = explode(',', $item);
            // print_r($newArray);
            
            foreach ($newArray as $field) {
                $parts = explode('=', $field);
                if ($parts[0] === 'sku') {
                    $sku = $parts[1];
                } elseif ($parts[0] === 'color') {
                    $color = $parts[1];
                }
            }
        
            return ['sku' => $sku, 'color' => $color];
        }, $convertToArray);
        
                

                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($result);
                echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a simple regex:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/sku=([0-9]+),color=([^|]*)/', $data, $matches);

$output = [];
foreach ($matches[1] as $k => $code) {
    $output[] = [
        'sku' => 'color',
        $code => $matches[2][$k],
    ];
}
```

(Assumes your SKU codes are all numeric, and that your color values don't contain the '|' character but could contain a comma)